# How can we persist the leds blinking rather than swithching from one led to other while using a demultiplexer

Tags: led

Demultiplexers are used for many outputs. In the case of led blinking, but its difficult to identify the leds that blinked. Since its output get switched between many leds. How can I digitally switch between many LEDS but have the output persist? Without switching between leds using a demultiplexer?

Answer (score 0):

> ... its difficult to identify the LEDs that blinked.

If you mean that it is difficult to read them then no, it's not. Multiplexing is the standard technique used for LED seven-segment displays. Provided the blink rate is fast enough and intense enough the light will appear continuous to a (relatively) static observer.

[image]

*Figure 1. A typical 50 mA LED (1) can be pulsed at 200 mA (2) for short duration (3). The note says 100 µs per 1000 µs.*

[image]

*Figure 2. Timing diagram for high-current driving of the LED.*

Using the timing of Figure 2 the flicker will not be visible to a human eye.

[image]

*Figure 3. For flicker-free displays a latch can be used. Source: [LEDnique](http://lednique.com/7-segment-display-basics/).*

For further reading see the link above to a short article I wrote on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an LED to be on all the time your logic says it should be on (so you could measure the voltage with a multimeter for example), then you need a bit (DIO pin) for every LED. 
Multiplexing is used to reduce the number of individual DIO pins you need to turn on each LED and uses scanning frequencies above the human threshold of persistence.

There are other ways to reduce the number of DIO pins per LED:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZKbkB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here you can have D1 on or D2 permanently on, both off ...but not both on non-multiplexed. 
Note ...the combined Vf for the LEDS D1, D2 must exceed the VCC voltage or they would both conduct.

Answer (score 0):

Persistence can be achieved by using a latch (or memory circuit), such as the 74HCT164. There are also other latches that can be used, a good thing to search for is open drain outputs if you want a low side switch or open collector if you want a high side switch.

[image]
Source: [LED circuits](http://www.qsl.net/yo5ofh/hobby%20circuits/led_circuits.htm)